# AWS ELB is adding http absolute path

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elb

We have tomcats running a Spring Security webapp.  The https is terminated at the ELB (443), then forwarded to tomcat on 8080.

However, when we log in,  a successful login redirects us to /welcome.html  but the redirect has an absolute path, and an http absolute path, which is wrong.

On my single tomcat local dev box, running on 8443,  the redirect is a relative /welcome.html and everything works fine. But on AWS,  it is redirected to http://whatever.com/welcome.html

How do I fix this so it stays https?

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with the ELB. Have you tried running a similar proxy on your local box using nginx or the like? My guess is the same thing would happen. You need to configure tomcat appropriately for the proxy to work properly.

Comment: This post for a related question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6643306/4072843